# Python ArgsParser Mutually exclusive groups with different set of arguments

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to add an argument parsing with the following logic:

1. A group which has either "-url (mandatory)  -u (optional) -p (optional)" or "-l (mandatory)" groups.

My code is like this:

```
def cmdline():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Report the performance numbers from log.');

    root_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True);

    url_group = root_group.add_argument_group();
    url_group.add_argument('-url', '--url', required=True, help='URL to get sysmgr.log.');
    url_group.add_argument('-u', '--user', required=False, default="admin", help='User name.');
    url_group.add_argument('-p', '--password', required=False, default="password", help='Password.');

    log_group = root_group.add_argument_group();
    log_group.add_argument('-l', '--log', required=True, help='sysmgr.log file location.');

    args = parser.parse_args();
    return args;
```

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "report_time.py", line 76, in <module>
    main();
  File "report_time.py", line 65, in main
    args = cmdline();
  File "report_time.py", line 32, in cmdline
    args = parser.parse_args();
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 1697, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 1729, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 1935, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 1875, in consume_optional
    take_action(action, args, option_string)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 1803, in take_action
    action(self, namespace, argument_values, option_string)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 990, in __call__
    parser.print_help()
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 2341, in print_help
    self._print_message(self.format_help(), file)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 2315, in format_help
    return formatter.format_help()
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 275, in format_help
    help = self._root_section.format_help()
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 205, in format_help
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 313, in _format_usage
    action_usage = format(optionals + positionals, groups)
  File "/usr/software/lib/python3.2/argparse.py", line 384, in _format_actions_usage
    start = actions.index(group._group_actions[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Where is my mistake here?

Thanks,
Pradip

Comment: `argument_group` is not designed to nest in a multually_exclusive_group.  Your code effectively defines one flat mutually_exclusive group with 4 actions, not 2 groups.  The error arises when it tries to format the usage (for an error message).  The usage formatting is brittle and cannot handle this kind of grouping.

Comment: Do your own post-parsing testing if you want anything fancier than a 'flat' xor test.